# Max value of a pdf

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function

We have $f_x(x;μ, σ^2) $ as the pdf of a normally distributed variable $X$.

What is the maximum value of the pdf?

I thought because the pdf is normally distributed, so it must be the case that mean = mode = median, so the max value is μ. However I was marked as wrong. Can somebody explain why is my answer wrong and what is the reasoning behind the correct answer?

Comment: Please use the [tag:self-study] tag and read its wiki

Comment: Hint: there is a difference between the max value of a function, and the value of the argument (known as $\operatorname{argmax}$) at which the max is obtained.

Comment: You were asked about the max value of the pdf, or the value for which the pdf has its maximum? The latter is $\mu$, the former is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$.

Comment: the maximum value of the pdf. It's written just like what I wrote in the question above.

Comment: @corey979 Obviously the wording makes a difference based on your answer, but can you elaborate the reasoning why?

Comment: Plot $f(x)=-(x-1)^2$. What's the max value of $f$? (Zero.) At what argument it takes its max value? (At $x=1$). You see the difference? Now take as $f(x)$ the pdf of the normal distribution.

Comment: To appreciate what "the pdf is normally distributed" could mean, note that the pdf *describes* a random variable and it's the random variable that is normally distributed.  As an analogy (intended to be somewhat amusing and memorable), consider a painting of a dog (its "pdf").  Although the dog might be hairy and aggressive, such terms don't even apply to the painting. If we were asked "where is the painting thickest" we should understand that to be where the *paint* is thickest, even though answers like "at the dog's mid-torso" might *sound* like they make sense.